# Does the limits exists?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let $f(x,y)$=$sin^2(x\sqrt{\mid y\mid)}\over{x^2+y^2}$

Does the limits exists when $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$?

I tried to use squeeze theorem but I don't know which function should I use to compare this limit with. Then I try to use x=y and see whether it is possible to get different values when the limit approaches from different directions.

However

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}$$sin^2(x\sqrt{\mid x \mid})\over 2x^2$

$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}$$sin^2(x^{3\over 2})\over 2x^2$

$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}$$sin(x^{3\over 2})\over 2x^{3\over 2}$$sin(x^{3\over 2})\over x^{3 \over 2}$$x$

$=0$

So, that show the limit is zero. Is there any other ideas or hints?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I try to substitute x=y and use $sin(x) \over x$ approaches to 1 when $x \rightarrow 0$, but this does not work since the limit will always be zero in this case. I think I should use squeeze theorem, But I don't know which function should I use to compare with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\sin(x)\le x$ and $x^2+y^2\ge 2|x||y|$ we find that

$$\frac{\sin^2(x\sqrt y)}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac{x^2|y|}{2|x||y|}=\frac12 |x|$$

Can you deduce now?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!